# Dimension matrix error in while loop Matlab

Tags: loops, matlab, matrix, dimension

I want my code to give me a final matrix of `31x5`

```
nplants=5
nhours=24

for j =nplants:-1:1
    for comb = fliplr(nchoosek(1:nplants, j).') 
        outage = ones(nhours, nplants); 
        outage(:, comb) = 0; % make columns zero

       prodout = outage.*prodordered;
        meritorder = prodout(:,1);
        for i=2:nplants,
        meritorder(:,i) = meritorder(:,i-1) + prodout(:,i);
        end
    active = zeros(nhours,nplants);
    active(:,1) = ones(nhours,1);
    
    for i=1:nhours,
        k = 1;
        while meritorder(i,k) <= hourlydata.demand(i)
                k = k+1;
            active(i,k) = 1;
        end
    end 
    supply = active.*prodout;
    varcost1 = active.*outage.*cncordered;
    totsupout = sum(supply,2);
    priceout = max(varcost1')';
    
    hourlyprofit1=(repmat(priceout,1,5)-varcost1).*prodout;
    profit1(:,j) = sum(hourlyprofit1);

    end
    
end
```

Where `prodordered` is a `24x5` matrix, `hourlydata.demand` is `24x1`, and `cncordered` is `24x5`.

I want `profit1` to store the results, becoming a `31x5` matrix.

When I try running this code, I get:

```
Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds. Index must not exceed 5.
        while meritorder(i,k) <= hourlydata.demand(i)
```

I don't understand my dimension matrix mistake in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're "trying" to look for a condition in the while line you've got to k=6. the condition that is tested is if `meritorder(i,6) <= hourlydata.demand(i)` . but `meritorder` is an array 24x5 so you cant access that col because it doesn't exist. so the whole condition is problematic to while.
Think of that as an `if x>1` condition where you haven't defined what `x` is.

You can solve it by replacing the while with a for loop (`for k=1:5`) following an `if` condition `if meritorder(i,k) <= hourlydata.demand(i);  active(i,k) = 1; end`